# Why is my font-face adding space at the baseline?

Tags: font-face, css

My font is doing something weird. There seems to be space being added below the font (Not the margin) that is pushing it up above the line-height. If I adjust the height it seems to be anchored to the bottom of the line height so instead of increasing the space below it actually pushes the top of the font above the line height. Is there any way, save adding margin or padding to the top, to make sure it's anchoring to the top of the line-height or middle?

[image]

CSS:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';src: url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_0_0.eot');src: url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_0_0.woff') format('woff'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Black';src: url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_1_0.eot');src: url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_1_0.woff') format('woff'),url('/us/_media/font/2CA9EF_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family:'AvenirLTStd-Black', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: inherit;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried altering the "display" css style?  e.g to inline-block?   IIRC, it has something to do with the additional height required for characters like q, g, p, etc which trail below the line  (?...)

Comment: You should include all the relevant code (including HTML) needed to reproduce the issue, describe the problem by referring exactly to items in the code or in the screenshot (expected rendering vs. actual rendering), and identify the font used and the method used to generate the font files. You should also text whether this happens with other fonts, too, in which case the problem description could be simplified. You should also remove all features that do not actually affect the problem, like probably letter spacing, font smoothing, etc.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd leave a comment for others Googling this issue.

It looks like you are using Avenir from MyFonts.com, which allows you to 'tweak' your webfont package.

I had the same issue as above, changing the **Line Height Adjustments** to use **Bounding Box (Match the bounding box of the glyphs, line gap will always be 0)** fixed the issue

I used the settings in the screenshot below:
[link to screenshot is down]

The idea is to increase line-height to decrease the space at the baseline, i.e.:

```
h1  {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer. I had the same issue with Proxima Nova downloaded from MyFonts.com and it also has that option that I didn't discover until later.

Comment: Yeah!! This has been bugging me for faaar too long! Thanks!!

Comment: Same exact problem 5 years later, same Avenir webfont purchased from myfonts.com  However, I cannot find the *Line Height Adjustments* option on myfonts.com UI to save my life.  I wish the link to your screenshot wasnt broken!

Answer (score 12):

I was on this for a while now and since I have no Myfonts.com account and the font is free font generated by FontsQuirrel or downloaded from GF I had to experiment. In PS my font looks correct by comparison,

Montserrat vs Open Sans

[image]

But webfont is completely off.

[image]

I was than forced to test several font editing software. First I tested [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) and could simply not figure out the proper metrics, than i got trial [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html) that has this great feature that auto calculates the metrics which when entered in FontForge fix the issue.

[image]

But paying $79.00 min to just fix this and never use the software again did not seem feasible and I also did not want to go back and forth between the two to get the metrics.  I continued to play with FontForge and finally found the solution.  You must reset all values to 0 in `Element -> Font Info -> OS/2 -> Metrics` and than uncheck the "Is Offset"

Instead another image here is short video that shows how to fix this

http://take.ms/rJpqh

**Note** that for some fonts it is better to uncheck the **Really use Typo metrics** which helped in my case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed my web-font by following your answer.

Comment: Grand! I removed Avenir bottom extra spacing using fontforge and following the steps in you answer

Comment: Resolved my problem on an Adobe font, this should be mark as the answer. Thank you for your investigation.

Comment: This is probably the most underrated answer of whole stackoverflow. I see tons of these questions and people always suggest `vertical-align` instead of `line-height`, and people say it didn’t change. I would always try a different font and see if the font would be aligned.  Tons of people with a similar problem are not helped. Some browser optimize a bad baseline, but font should be correct in the beginning

Comment: EDIT: One could also just use FontCreator to get the Values and then put them in in fontforge. The exact problem at my font was that Chrome Web Browser took the Win ascender and descender Value and Safari and Chrome Mobile took the Typo ascender or the standard ascender

Comment: Thanks for a video!

Comment: There's an easier way to do this now. Use the "Vertical Metrics" auto adjustment setting on the fontsquirrel webfont generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score -3):

The attribute you have missed out is 'vertical-align' and it is probably causing all of the trouble
This tells the browser where to align the text
It has the following values (not all are listed):

- baseline
- sub
- super
- middle
- top
- bottom

To find out more click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align%20%22MDN%20-%20vertical-align)

Comment: Hmm... Tried some of those. Didn't seem to change anything. This was actually my first thought but I'm not seeing any effect when I change it.